# Pressing either the "down arrow" and "End" opens Dash Home

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with a Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 800.  Every time I press either the down arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> OR the <kbd>End</kbd> key the Dash Home opens up.

- I've checked my keyboard shortcuts and that doesn't seem to be the issue.
- I tested what key-press is actually detected using the Keyboard Shortcut utility and <kbd>↓</kbd>  results in a "Mod2 + Super R" and the <kbd>End</kbd> key gives a "Super L".

Before I swap out the keyboard, I figured I'd see if anyone else has experience this before.  My old Logitech keyboard had no issues on the same system.

Comment: Thanks for editing to make it more readable SimplySimon - I'll have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: See [markdown help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for information on markdown. Have you installed any applications that might mess with keyboard shortcuts? xbindkeys, Unity Tweak Tool, Compiz Config, etc?

Comment: Can you add what the terminal says when you run the command `xev | grep keycode` in a terminal and press 'End' or down arrow in the opened window?